# Can my grandfather receive money in the state of Wisconsin if he's unemployed?

Tags: united-states, benefits, unemployment, wisconsin, welfare-benefits

**Please read entire post before answering.**

Hello! My grandfather has lived here in the U.S for the past eight years. He immigrated here in 2010 and does have a green card (no citizenship). He also has Social Security, but has never worked here in the U.S or received any federal benefits.

My grandfather was wondering if their was a way he could get any money for being unemployed. He hasn’t attempted to get employed, mainly because he doesn’t have a lot of employable skills. He’s old, has back problems, has had two stents placed in his heart with surgery (with his own money) and doesn’t know English. He isn’t disabled with anything at the moment though.

He doesn’t want to receive Food Stamps either. What he’d ideally want is a sum of money each month (a small amount, pocket money as he likes to call it) to help him go about his daily life. Right now, my family is financing everything for him. He’d like to not be dependent on us as much.

If anyone needs more information to answer this question, let me know. I’ve love detailed answers to this as we are struggling to find solutions for him.

Comment: Might he possibly have unclaimed state or other pension benefits from his previous country?

Answer (score 8):

To be eligible for unemployment benefits in Wisconsin, you must have been [employed in the *base period*](https://dwd.wisconsin.gov/uiben/handbook/english/contentspart5.htm), which is a year-long period prior to the date you apply for unemployment benefits. Since your grandfather has not been employed for the past 8 years, I don’t think he is eligible for unemployment benefits.

Comment: _and_ (with very limited exceptions not applicable here) you must be 'available for' and actively seeking work; see the preceding part 4. Although if gramps is _willing_ to work, there probably _are_ free/subsidized services to help learn English and some job skills; that's a different Q.